# How do you start the quest "The Thunder Forge"?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How do you start the quest [The Thunder Forge](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=32593/the-thunder-forge)?

My server has unlocked all the stages of the Isle of Thunder.

Comment: All the stages of the Island of thunder

Comment: Are you playing on a private server, or on Blizzard's official servers? In case of a private server: there's nothing we can do to help, as private servers tend to have quest breaking bugs that do not officially exist, in which case this question may be closed as `Too localized`, since a private server bug may apply to one private server, but not necessarily to others, or the solution to that bug may be different, depending on the private server you're playing at.

Comment: Does sound like a private server.

Comment: It's on wowhead, so I'm inclined to believe it's legitimate.

Comment: @fbueckert The quest is yes. The problem is he said "My server has unlocked". That's your first clue this is a private server.

Comment: @deutschZuid I haven't played WoW in years; I remember some content used to be gated, though.  Is this something that is fully available?

Comment: @fbueckert Once certain content becomes available, it becomes available for all the Blizzard servers (unlike the days of Ahn'Qiraj). So if someone's talking about 'unlocking' for a particular server, then they are talking about private servers.

Comment: The Isle of Thunder is in fact gated, and the Thunder Forge needed to be unlocked by server, so he's probably not talking about a private server. Although, I don't really see what the problem is.

Comment: @deutschZuid No, Island is gated and if you haven't played the game don't post comments which might lead to downvoting legimite questions.

Comment: I don't understand how some of you assume I am playing on a private server. I posted an answer now why I had a hard time finding this. The quest is part of the Legendary questline and the prequests needs to be completed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quest seems to be part of a chain. Here is the order of the quests.

Neutral

[5.0]  Stranger in a Strange Land
[5.0]  A Legend in the Making
[5.0]  The Strength of One's Foes
[5.0]  Trial of the Black Prince

Honored

[5.0]  Fear Itself
[5.0]  Breath of the Black Prince 
[5.0]  Incoming...
[5.1]  The Measure of a Leader
[5.1]  A Test of Valor
[5.1]  The Prince's Pursuit

Revered

[5.1]  The Lion Roars or  Glory to the Horde
[5.1]  A Change of Command
[5.1]  Call of the Packmaster or  The Soul of the Horde
[5.1]  The Thunder King
[5.2]  Meet Me Upstairs
[5.2]  Secrets of the First Empire
[5.2]  I Need a Champion

Exalted

[5.2]  The Thunder Forge
[5.2]  Spirit of the Storm Lord
[5.2]  The Crown of Heaven
[5.2]  Echoes of the Titans
[5.2]  Heart of the Thunder King
[5.2]  A Reckoning

[5.3]  Celestial Blessings
[5.3]  Cloak of Virtue
[5.3]  Preparing to Strike

Answer (score 2):

The quest in question is a part of legendary quest chain. To unlock it, you have to do all quest prior to "The Tunder Forge".

To start legendary quest chain you have to be level 90 and start quest ["Stranger in a Stramge Land"](http://www.wowdb.com/quests/31488-stranger-in-a-strange-land). After it, you simple have to follow all the quests in the chain which will eventually lead to The Tunder Forge.

If you have already done some quests in the chain, check your Quest Log. Quests which are part of legendary chain will be marked as < legendary > in a Quest Log. If you have none of them, visit Wrathion located in the [Tavern in the Mists](http://www.wowwiki.com/Tavern_in_the_Mists).

If you are sure you done everything what was asked from you, but you still can't access the quest, simply contact Game Master via in built Customer Suport (red question mark on your [micro bar](http://www.curseforge.com/media/images/37/536/microbar.jpg)).

Answer (score 0):

From your own link: talk to Wrathion in his whelp form at the Thunder Forge. If you can't find him, do a `/tar Wrathion` and look for his position on the mini map once you target him.